# How to ensure const int has unique value in C++

Tags: c++, enums

I have some kind of container and objects can use it for storing some of their data. Each stored object should have its id, eg. MY_GL_CONTEXT, FUNNY_CONF_OBJECT etc. I would like to store these identifiers distributed across objects which will use them. Example: objects of class Model want to store there data using id MY_GL_CONTEXT.

I want to know, what kind of type should I use for these ids to avoid conflicts between classes. If I use static const int then there could happen, that Object::MY_GL_CONTEXT will have the same int value as Something::FUNNY_CONF_OBJECT so they will colide when using my container.

Thank you.

Comment: If you can use C++11, you can use strongly typed `enum`s. This way you *have* to qualify enum identifiers explicitly and cannot have them alias with members of other `enum`s.

Comment: Do the values need to persist across different executions (e.g. are they saved?), or do they just need to be consistent during a single instance of your program?

Comment: The first question I should have asked is why you need no conflict between classes. Are there situations in your code where you need to distinguish between `Something::FUNNY_CONF_OBJECT` and `Object::MY_GL_CONTEXT`? You may need to differentiate between constants that are somewhat related (say `MY_GL_CONTEXT`vs my `MY_DIRECT3D_CONTEXT`) but sheldom between unrelated constants (if you do you probably are having design issues).

Comment: The question of MikeGM is quite important. It looks like you want to have type information in the container. If the objects are only required in runtime then the normal way to check for types is to store pointers to dynamically allocated objects in the container and check per dynamic_cast. 1.: Define base class <code>CData</code>. 2.: Define container of <code>CData*</code>. 3.: Put ptrs to objects of derived types (e.g. <code>CDer*</code>) in. 4.: When needed check object ptr pObj in container per <code>dynamic_cast<CDer*>(pObj)</code>. If the type is wrong you get pObj==0.

Comment: thokra: i can use C++11 but I would prefer to have identifiers defined in multiple files.  MikeGM: I dont need that kind of persistent values at all. I will use it probably only for some kind of runtime caching. So when it will be run next time, it will be cached again.  SJuan76: These identifiers will be used in one container class. Classes will use the container and I want to prevent conflicts between multiple classes using that container at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, there are a few unique things.

Each object has a unique address. Cast to `void*`, it can be compared for equality. Different objects have different addresses, so this makes a usuable id.

Each polymorphic type has its own run-time type information, obtainable via `typeid`. This is ordered via `std::type_info::before`.

Due to separate compilation, it's virtually impossible to guarantee that `const int` values are unique. In fact, due to separate compilation, two .cpp files can be compiled at the same moment. How would one compiler know what `int` value the other compiler will pick?

Comment: I was thinking about this and came to same conclusion. Still thanks for detailed comment. I can use static casting and templates (but I am not sure yet, how could I use it in particular).

Answer (score 1):

Create a shared `.h` file and DEFINE the different values there, that way it will be easy to spot duplicated values (as long as you keep them ordered). Include that file everywhere it is needed.

```
// To avoid duplication
#ifndef CONSTANTS   
#define CONSTANTS
#define MY_GL_CONTEXT 1
#define FUNNY_CONF_OBJECT 2
...
#endif
```

Comment: Better yet, make it an `enum` so you don't have to give numbers individually, and by omitting the values, you also make sure the numbers are never the same.

Comment: This is one of two possible backup-plans (probably the version with enum as Shahbaz said). But I think that the identifiers names should not be part of definition of my container class. I want to have simple, plain and multifunctional container class - and other classes will use it as they want to (using their own identifiers).

Comment: The second backup-plan is that the key for the container (the identifier) would consist of two elements -> first would be type of object using the container (Object or something according to example given in my first post) and the second part of kye would be the const int or enum identifier (eg. Object::MY_GL_OBJECT or Something::FUNNY_CONF_OBJECT). Problem of this solution is that it would complicate declaration of containers interface and I will lose serious part of desired simplicity.